# Calling a method of a derived class in vector of superior class

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I have an vector of superior type class

```
vector<Parent> parents;
```

then i'm adding a derived class types let's say daughter and son

```
Son tempSon;
tempSon.setAge(7);
tempSon.setName("John");
parents.push_back(tempSon);
Daughter tempDaughter;
tempDaughter.setAge(9);
tempDaughter.setName("Emily");
parents.push_back(tempDaughter);
```

Now what the problem is when i iterate through the vector and call methods like

```
parents.at(0).printName();
```

The parent method gets called which does nothing and I want to call a child method. Another thing is that i do not know the type of the object passed(e.g whether son or daughter) so i can't cast it. I tried to use typeid(object) and it prints the parent class name instead of child class.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am not a c++ expert but I think you should post the class definition.

Comment: the parent class is basically empty and child classes have all the specific code within them

Comment: For the polymorphism to work you need either references (which are not possible to store in containers) or pointers.

Comment: You should provide the classes because this is where the problem is. If you want the child method to be called, you have to declare the method virtual in the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you should store POINTERS in the vector, instead of a copy of the object, becuase only the PARENT part will be stored.

Once you store the pointer, you can cast to the child class and call the correct method, or simply, make the method virtual in the parent class and call it without casting.

Answer (score 0):

Are your classes have declared function as virtual? If no, there will be no polymorphic behavior.

//Yes, and vector of pointer to class.